# Seg Fault from dictionary initialization Python

Tags: python, dictionary, segmentation-fault, list-initialization

So I am working on a project that deals with a large number of vehicles and transmissions between those vehicles. I have a working code that works well for small numbers of vehicles, but when I start using large numbers ~500 vehicles then the program will seg fault about half the time. I have backtraced the seg fault using faulthandler() and the dictionary initialization is where the program currently faults. Here is the code for the dictionary initialization:

```
for j in range(self.num_vehicles):  # for each vehicle
        if self.timeIndex == 0:
            self.vehicles[j].pseudo_random_number(0)
    self.seconds = []
    for j in range(500):
        mso = self.vehicles[j].full_mso_range()
        vehicle_transmissions = []
        for k in range(500):
            vehicle_transmissions.append(0)
        # Iterate through all of the other vehicles besides vehicle j
        for k in range(j+1, j+500):
            distance = float(np.ceil(np.sqrt(
                (self.vehicles[j].position[0] - self.vehicles[k % self.num_vehicles].position[0]) ** 2.0 +
                (self.vehicles[j].position[1] - self.vehicles[k % self.num_vehicles].position[1]) ** 2.0 +
                (self.vehicles[j].position[2] - self.vehicles[k % self.num_vehicles].position[2]) ** 2.0)))
            
            transmission = {"receiverID": int(k%500),
                            "distance": 0,
                            "receivedpower": 0,
                            "successfuldecode": 0}
            
            vehicle_transmissions[transmission["receiverID"]] = transmission  # store transmission
        self.vehicles[j].transmissions = vehicle_transmissions.copy()  # save transmission to vehicle
        self.vehicles[j].frame += 1  # increase frame
        self.seconds.append(mso)  # record MSO in a list that helps with collisions
```

The Seg Fault occurs where the transmission is allocated. I have tried to simplify the allocation so try and isolate the fault but I have had no luck so far. Any advice would be appreciated.

Also this code is called through a c++ code and gdb only tells me that the seg fault is happening in this function.

Comment: maybe you should use `print()` to see values in variables before error. Or maybe you should put code in try/except - and maybe it will catch problem.

Comment: maybe you should use `self.num_vehicles` instead of `500` in all places.

Comment: Thanks so much for looking at this, I changed {self.num_vehicles} to 500 to try and make the problem as simple as possible. Also I tried print statements for all variables and try catch statements as well. So far nothing turns up, all I get for all those efforts was the debugger telling me it happens when I initialize the dict

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being a error in the python to C++ interface. It only happens when there is a large number of calls, it seems to lose its place in memory and when it accesses that point again hits an error. I ended up just writing the complete code in C++ which solves the problem. If anyone else reads this its easier to go from C++ which calls Python rather than Python calling C++.

Comment: Please consider providing some source code to support the given answer explaining show how it solves the problem.